# Python's "in" set operator

Tags: python

I'm a little confused about the python `in` operator for sets.

If I have a set `s` and some instance `b`, is it true that `b in s` means "*is there some element `x` in `s` such that `b == x` is `true`*"?

Comment: Computer Scientist.  I'm just a little confused because the documentation says "Test x for membership in s."  To me that could mean "the instance x is contained in s" or "some instance exists in s that has the same value as x".  I don't know whether this is an identity or equality comparison.

Comment: @Dejas: Since you're aware that Python has two operators Equality comparison and identity comparison, you should be able to construct an experiment that confirms each.  It would help if you posted that experiment.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Yes, but it *also* means [`hash(b) == hash(x)`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__), so equality of the items isn't enough to make them the same.

Comment: Ok so "is there an element x in s such that hash(b) == hash(x) and x == b"?

Comment: If someone implemented his class's hash function in a twisted way, this is what he may get (and deserve).

Comment: I think the documentation on [membership testing](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) should state more clearly that hash equality is a precondition for `set`, `frozenset` and `dict`. An improvement like that was discussed in a bug report in 2015, but unfortunately it got closed in 2019: https://bugs.python.org/issue23987#msg241661.

Answer (score 111):

That's right. You could try it in the interpreter like this:

```
>>> a_set = set(['a', 'b', 'c'])

>>> 'a' in a_set
True

>>>'d' in a_set
False
```

Comment: This is not a very good test since string constants are often interned (try `a = 'a'; b = 'a'; a is b`). I tried it with `a = (1, 2, 3); b = (1, 2, 3); a == b; hash(a) == hash(b); a is b; a in set([b])` instead.

Answer (score 15):

Yes it can mean so, or it can be a simple iterator. For example:
Example as iterator:

```
a=set(['1','2','3'])
for x in a:
 print ('This set contains the value ' + x)
```

Similarly as a check:

```
a=set('ILovePython')
if 'I' in a:
 print ('There is an "I" in here')
```

edited: edited to include sets rather than lists and strings

Comment: What does this have to do with sets?

Comment: well I suppose a list or even a string can be considered to have similar properties to a set. They are a collection of elements.

Comment: No, sets have an additional condition for a containment check that sequences do not.

Answer (score 7):

Sets behave different than dicts, you need to use set operations like issubset():

```
>>> k
{'ip': '123.123.123.123', 'pw': 'test1234', 'port': 1234, 'debug': True}
>>> set('ip,port,pw'.split(',')).issubset(set(k.keys()))
True
>>> set('ip,port,pw'.split(',')) in set(k.keys())
False
```

Comment: That's interesting. And a great real-world application as well.

Comment: This is precisely the surprising result that brought me here.

Comment: why surprising? the `in` operator tests for _**element** membership_, and that holds for sets, dicts, lists, tuples and so on. The second test is (naively) testing if _the set_ is a an _element_ of the keys set. And no, it is not: the set of keys contains only keys, not sets

Answer (score 3):

Strings, though they are not `set` types, have a valuable `in` property during validation in scripts:

```
yn = input("Are you sure you want to do this? ")
if yn in "yes":
    #accepts 'y' OR 'e' OR 's' OR 'ye' OR 'es' OR 'yes'
    return True
return False
```

I hope this helps you better understand the use of `in` with this example.

Comment: That's not a set. Nor are strings mutable.

Comment: `... or 'e' or 'es' or 's'`. Consider just deleting this pointlessly wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

**List's __contains__** method uses the **__eq__** method of its elements. Whereas **set's __contains__** uses **__hash__**. Have a look to the following example that I wish will be explicit:

```
class Salary:
    """An employee receives one salary for each job he has."""

    def __init__(self, value, job, employee):
        self.value = value
        self.job = job
        self.employee = employee

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.employee} works as {self.job} and earns {self.value}"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """A salary is equal to another if value is equal."""
        return self.value == other.value

    def __hash__(self):
        """A salary can be identified with the couple employee-job."""
        return hash(self.employee) + hash(self.job)

alice = 'Alice'
bob = 'Bob'
engineer = 'engineer'
teacher = 'teacher'

alice_engineer = Salary(10, engineer, alice)
alice_teacher = Salary(8, teacher, alice)
bob_engineer = Salary(10, engineer, bob)

print(alice_engineer == alice_teacher)
print(alice_engineer == bob_engineer, '\n')

print(alice_engineer is alice_engineer)
print(alice_engineer is alice_teacher)
print(alice_engineer is bob_engineer, '\n')

alice_jobs = set([alice_engineer, alice_teacher])
print(alice_jobs)
print(bob_engineer in alice_jobs)  # IMPORTANT
print(bob_engineer in list(alice_jobs))  # IMPORTANT
```

Console prints:

```
False
True 

True
False
False 

{Alice works as teacher and earns 8, Alice works as engineer and earns 10}
False
True
```