# How to select just 1 element in a list for a if statement

Tags: python, list

This program prints 'Select a Valid function!' even if the input is correct, why is that? And how can I tell the program that I'm talking about individual elements in a list and not the entire list?

```
sign = input ("Enter the sign: ")
if sign != ["+","-","*","/"]:
    print ("Select a Valid function!")
else:
    print ("Let's Begin")
if sign =="+":
    no1 = input("Enter the first number: ")
    no2 = input("Enter the second number: ")
    print (int(no1)+int(no2))
elif sign =="-":
    no1 = input("Enter the first number: ")
    no2 = input("Enter the second number: ")
    print (int(no1)-int(no2))
elif sign =="*":
    no1 = input("Enter the first number: ")
    no2 = input("Enter the second number: ")
    print (int(no1)*int(no2))
elif sign =="/":
    no1 = input("Enter the first number: ")
    no2 = input("Enter the second number: ")
    print (int(no1)/int(no2))
```

Comment: `if sign != ["+","-","*","/"]:` won't work because you're testing _equality_ against a list. Instead, you want to test for _membership_ so that'll need to be changed to `if sign not in ["+","-","*","/"]:`

Comment: `if sign not in '+-*/':`

Comment: Yup, like the others said, this is about membership! Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705378/pythons-in-set-operator

Answer (score 0):

```
if sign != ["+","-","*","/"]:
```

That will always be true, because `sign` is not a list, so it will never be *equal* to a list.

You want to use the `in` operator instead:

```
if sign not in ["+","-","*","/"]:
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you're not using the correct operator to check if something is in a list.

But you don't even need that check. Just add an `else:` statement after all the `if/elif`.

```
sign = input ("Enter the sign: ")
if sign =="+":
    no1 = input("Enter the first number: ")
    no2 = input("Enter the second number: ")
    print (int(no1)+int(no2))
elif sign =="-":
    no1 = input("Enter the first number: ")
    no2 = input("Enter the second number: ")
    print (int(no1)-int(no2))
elif sign =="*":
    no1 = input("Enter the first number: ")
    no2 = input("Enter the second number: ")
    print (int(no1)*int(no2))
elif sign =="/":
    no1 = input("Enter the first number: ")
    no2 = input("Enter the second number: ")
    print (int(no1)/int(no2))
else:
    print ("Select a Valid function!")
```

This way you don't need to keep the list consistent with the list of signs that you implement.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said change:

```
if sign != ["+","-","*","/"]:
```

to

```
if sign not in ["+","-","*","/"]:
```

to test for non-membership of a list.

---

You can also cut down on a lot of duplication in your code and avoid the `if...elif` statements by using a dictionary of [operators](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/operator.html) like this:

```
import operator

ops = {'+': operator.add,
       '-': operator.sub,
       '*': operator.mul,
       '/': operator.truediv
      }

sign = input ("Enter the sign: ")

if sign not in ops:
    print ("Select a Valid function!")
else:
    print ("Let's Begin")
    no1 = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
    no2 = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
    ans = ops[sign](no1, no2)
    print(ans)
```